# MVC how to hide an ID field when creating VIEW using Scaffolding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-annotations, poco, t4

I have a Class generated with POCO T4 Template, I'm using this code to adding to the Partial Class some DataAnnotation.

I would like to know:

How to hide the field OptionId (in the DB is a Primary Key with          IDENTITY) so the User does not need input this value in the View (but with setting in the model).

Also I would    like to know if    `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`    is REQUIRED or EF with POCO will create automatically the new ID (is IDENTITY)

```
namespace MyProject.Models
    {
        [MetadataType(typeof(ReOptionMetadata))]
        public partial class ReOption
        {
            private class ReOptionMetadata
            {
                [Key]
                [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
                [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)] // Is it correct?
                public int OptionId { get; set; }
                [Required]
                public string Name { get; set; }
                [Required]
                public string Value { get; set; }
                [Required]
                public string Description { get; set; }
                [Required]
                public string NoteInternal { get; set; }    
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`@Html.HiddenFieldFor(model => model.ColumnWhichContainsTheId)` ?

Comment: Is it possible to have in the MODEL? in the view is not problem to hide it

Comment: you cant hide the ID in the MODEL because u need the REFERENCE ID to update your model/entity (delete,change or similar interaction @view) ?? what's ur goal??